# How to set form field values based on a preceding select control using jquery?

Tags: jquery

How can I set the value of the hidden fields "type_id[]" based on the preceding select control using jquery?

I want to set the value of the hidden fields that follow the control but stop setting values at the next select control so that the next select control can set the values of the hidden "type_id[]" fields that follow it, and so on.

The number of sub_budget_amount divs are variable and are added dynamically, so I don't know how many there will be.

the HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label">Budget Type</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="budget_type_id[]" name="budget_type_id[]" class="form-control input-md" required="required">
        <option value="1">option 1</option>
        <option value="2">option 2</option>
        <option value="3">option 3</option>
        <option value="4">option 4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="sub-budget-amount">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Default</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="hidden" name="type_id[]"  class="type_id">
      <input type="hidden" name="program_budget_id[]"  class="program_budget_id">
      <input id="amount" name="amount[]" type="text" class="form-control input-md budget_amount" >
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="sub-budget-amount">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Default</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="hidden" name="type_id[]"  class="type_id">
      <input type="hidden" name="program_budget_id[]"  class="program_budget_id">
      <input id="amount" name="amount[]" type="text" class="form-control input-md budget_amount" >
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="sub-budget-amount">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Default</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="hidden" name="type_id[]"  class="type_id">
      <input type="hidden" name="program_budget_id[]"  class="program_budget_id">
      <input id="amount" name="amount[]" type="text" class="form-control input-md budget_amount" >
    </div>
</div>



<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label">Budget Type</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="budget_type_id[]" name="budget_type_id[]" class="form-control input-md" required="required">
        <option value="1">option 1</option>
        <option value="2">option 2</option>
        <option value="3">option 3</option>
        <option value="4">option 4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="sub-budget-amount">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Default</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="hidden" name="type_id[]"  class="type_id">
      <input type="hidden" name="program_budget_id[]"  class="program_budget_id">
      <input id="amount" name="amount[]" type="text" class="form-control input-md budget_amount" >
    </div>
</div>



<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label">Budget Type</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select id="budget_type_id[]" name="budget_type_id[]" class="form-control input-md" required="required">
        <option value="1">option 1</option>
        <option value="2">option 2</option>
        <option value="3">option 3</option>
        <option value="4">option 4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

etc...

and the jquery ~ no idea how to do this.

```
$('#budget_type_id').change(function(){

    // set as many hidden fields as we find after the select control 
    // and stop setting values when we find the next select control

});
```

**UPDATE - SOLVED**

I got this solved with some help from below, the solution was to enclose the select control and it's hidden fields in a container and then search the container for the hidden classes:

```
$(".budget_type_id").change(function(){

    //get the value of the select options
    var option = $(this).val();
    var container = $(this).parent().parent().parent();

    //var spans = $( "span" );
    $(container).find(".type_id").val(option);    

});
```

New fiddle here: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xd2drq7y/74/)

Comment: I didn't realize you wanted to set the values of the non hidden input elements in your html as well. I must have missed that in your question. You had stated that you wanted to change the value of the hidden input type_id[] from what I gathered.  You are not using the spans in your Jquery code above.  I am curious why it is needed?

Comment: Sorry - the spans were left over [not needed] as to the non hidden elements, in the fiddle? ~ I just changed them to text types so I could see the values changing without having to view source/inspector etc.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I hope your project goes smoothly. Let me know if you need any more help.

Answer (score 1):

There are some changes I had to make to your html and javascript in order for your code to work. jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/larryjoelane/xd2drq7y/50/

I changed all of the select option id's to classes because you can't have more than one element on a webpage with same id.

I also removed the [] from the selector.

Here is what the changed line of html looks like:

```
 <select class="budget_type_id" name="budget_type_id[]" class="form-control input-md" required="required">
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label">Budget Type</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select class="budget_type_id" name="budget_type_id[]" class="form-control input-md" required="required">
        <option value="1">option 1</option>
        <option value="2">option 2</option>
        <option value="3">option 3</option>
        <option value="4">option 4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="sub-budget-amount">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Default</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="hidden" name="type_id[]"  class="type_id">
      <input type="hidden" name="program_budget_id[]"  class="program_budget_id">
      <input id="amount" name="amount[]" type="text" class="form-control input-md budget_amount" >
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="sub-budget-amount">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Default</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="hidden" name="type_id[]"  class="type_id">
      <input type="hidden" name="program_budget_id[]"  class="program_budget_id">
      <input id="amount" name="amount[]" type="text" class="form-control input-md budget_amount" >
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="sub-budget-amount">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Default</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="hidden" name="type_id[]"  class="type_id">
      <input type="hidden" name="program_budget_id[]"  class="program_budget_id">
      <input id="amount" name="amount[]" type="text" class="form-control input-md budget_amount" >
    </div>
</div>



<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label">Budget Type</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select class="budget_type_id" name="budget_type_id[]" class="form-control input-md" required="required">
        <option value="1">option 1</option>
        <option value="2">option 2</option>
        <option value="3">option 3</option>
        <option value="4">option 4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="sub-budget-amount">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Default</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <input type="hidden" name="type_id[]"  class="type_id">
      <input type="hidden" name="program_budget_id[]"  class="program_budget_id">
      <input id="amount" name="amount[]" type="text" class="form-control input-md budget_amount" >
    </div>
</div>



<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4 control-label">Budget Type</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <select class="budget_type_id" name="budget_type_id[]" class="form-control input-md" required="required">
        <option value="1">option 1</option>
        <option value="2">option 2</option>
        <option value="3">option 3</option>
        <option value="4">option 4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript: **Note:** You will notice I changed the on click event so that it will recognize the select element when they are dynamically added to the document object model

```
     $(document).on("change",".budget_type_id",function(){


         //get the value of the select options
         var option = $(this).val();

  //set the value  of the next .type_id hidden input
  $(this).parent().parent().next("div").find(".type_id").html(option);



});
```

Comment: Wont this set ~all~ the hidden .type_id fields in the form? not just the ones that are between select boxes?

Comment: let me set up a fiddle and test it.

Comment: Alright I finally have what I believe is a more robust solution to your problem. I included a jsfiddle so that you can test it.

Comment: Close, your fiddle does only the next hidden field, but provided a clue and a direction on how to set all the following fields. I'll update the question with a new fiddle.